# Pandas output to XML

Tags: python, pandas, xml

I am using PANDAS to read and modify an XML file. The file has this structure

```
<root>
   <child>
     <Grandchild>
         <element> ... 
     </Grandchild>
   </child>
</root>
```

The output looks like this

```
<root>
   <Grandchild>
      <element> ...
    </Grandchild>
</root>
```

In order for the file to be read it HAS to have the "child" node. How can I can I get the to_xml() method to add that node to the dataframe?

I have attempted to use etree, and other xml imports, but would really like to stick to the pandas library.

Comment: Lets see some python ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I would use the **stylesheet** parameter, and apply an XSLT that appends the `child` element if missing.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="/root[not(child)]">
      <xsl:copy>
        <child>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </child>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Something like:

```
dataframe.to_xml("example.xml", stylesheet='example.xslt')
```